# How does the angular velocity of the charged disk affect the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-velocity

How does the angular velocity of the rotating charged disk affect the magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

If the axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane of the disk and through its center of mass, and you know the charge density as a function of the radius, then the magnetic field on the axis can be calculated as a sum of contributions from many thin circular loops of current. In that case, the magnetic field will be directly proportional to the angular velocity. In other cases the calclation will be more complex, but it is likely the field strength will still be proportional to the that velocity.